# React native screen transition

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I made a screen transition slide from the bottom on the Stack navigator using the next code:

```
<Stack.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Home"
  screenListeners={({navigation, route}) => ({
    focus: () => {
      setIsTabBarVisible(route.name === 'Home' ? true : false);
    },
  })}
  screenOptions={{
    animation: 'slide_from_bottom',
    header: () => undefined,
}}>
```

This new screen comes from the bottom, which is right. But I also want an old screen to go up instead of just being static in the background. Is it possible?

Comment: Did you try using navigation.push instead of navigation.navigate?

Comment: @Abe I need transition animation, how it is related to push or navigate?

Comment: Push adds a new screen onto the stack, triggering the animation, while navigate will use the old screen if it already exists in the stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently using `@react-navigation/native-stack`, but you need first to install `@react-navigation/stack` and to switch everything to it.

'Native-stack' give you screen options for pre-built animation, but you need more control with 'stack'.

Properly code for this effect is:

```
 const MyTransition = {
      gestureDirection: 'horizontal',
      transitionSpec: {
        open: TransitionSpecs.TransitionIOSSpec,
        close: TransitionSpecs.TransitionIOSSpec,
      },
      headerStyleInterpolator: HeaderStyleInterpolators.forFade,
      cardStyleInterpolator: ({current, next, layouts}) => {
        return {
          cardStyle: {
            transform: [
              {
                translateY: next
                  ? next.progress.interpolate({
                      inputRange: [0, 1],
                      outputRange: [0, -layouts.screen.height],
                    })
                  : current.progress.interpolate({
                      inputRange: [0, 1],
                      outputRange: [layouts.screen.height, 0],
                    }),
              },
            ],
          },
        };
      },
    };
```

Then you need to set it for every screen where you want this kind of animation. Simply add it to `options`.